# Total number of Subsets

Tags: algorithm

I am getting curious about this question..

How many ways can you choose a subset from the set P = {1, 2, 3, .. n}? The subset S should meet the following condition:

When you choose x (x ∈ P, x is an element of the set P) to create S, you cannot choose a * x and b * x for S.

Constraints :

```
1 <= n <= 1000
2 <= a < b <= n
b % a != 0 ( b is not divisible by a)
```

Example :

```
n = 3 , a = 2, b = 3
so total subsets are 5 ,i.e, {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {2, 3} 
as if in a particular subset there is 1 so 1*2 = 2 and 1*3 cant be there.
so {1,2}, {1,3} and {1,2,3} can't be there
```

Comment: a*x ? b*x ? can you kindly clarify what are those ?

Comment: a*x = multiplication of a and x ... so for b*x

Comment: a and b are two given integers and b is not divisible by a

Comment: What's the condition exactly? You can't choose x ∈ P to be a member of S such that `x*a` *what*?  Such that x*a ∈ P?  Such that x*a = pi()?  Such that x*a > 1000?

Comment: if x is there in a subset then a*x and b*x should not be there..
example :

a=2;
b=3;
so total subsets are 5 , i.e., {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {2, 3}

Comment: Perhaps you cold update the question with the full constraint, for improved legibility?

Comment: In short I believe what OP asks for is to count number of subsets P such that for any two numbers a and b there is no common divisor of a and b in P.

Comment: What is wrong with this question. Doesn't the algorithm tag imply we need an algorithm to do the counting?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

This is related to **[sequence A051026 : Number of primitive subsequences of {1, 2, ..., n}](http://oeis.org/A051026)** in OEIS, the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

I don't think there is any easy way to calculate the terms. Even the recursive computations are not trivial, except when `n` is prime where:

```
a(n) = 2 * a(n-1) - 1
```

---

Both the problem here and "A051026" can be thought of subproblems of a generalization of the above sequence. "A051026" is the instance with `(a,b,..) = (2,3,4,5...)`, e.g. "all the integers >= 2".

Comment: This is wrong. {1,2,4}, with a = 1000, b=100000 is a valid set.

Comment: @Knoothe Maybe I didn't understand what he is asking. I wait for the OP to clarify. If I'm wrong, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: a,b are inputs, and only two are given. I interpreted the problem as: given n,a,b can you give an algorithm to count the number of possible subsets. btw, OP is most likely a she.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be easier to calculate the complimentary- that is the number of subsets of S that **are not allowed**. This is the number of subsets of `S` for each there is at least one pair `(a,b)` such that `a` divides `b`. After you calculate that number M' simply subtract it from the total number of subsets of S that is 2<sup>n</sup>.

Now to calculate the number of subsets of `S` that are not allowed you will have to apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The solution is not very easy to implement but I don't think there is an alternative approach.